# Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, javafx

Any clue on what could be causing this Exception based off my current code?

When running the following code:

Main.java

```
package application;
    
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Button runButton = new Button("Run");

        runButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            Test test = new Test();
        });
        
        GridPane GridBox = new GridPane();
        
        GridBox.add(runButton, 0, 0);

        Scene Scene = new Scene(GridBox, 380, 150);
        
        primaryStage.setScene(Scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
package application;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Test {
    WebDriver driver;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test obj = new Test();
        obj.setupWebsite();
    }
    
    public void setupWebsite() {
        //Creates Chrome Window.
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        //Sets up window to maximize and go to Brink website.
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

All I get is the following:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
    at application.Main.lambda$0(Main.java:18)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8875)
    at javafx.controls@21.0.1/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:207)
    at javafx.controls@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3984)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1890)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2708)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 46 more
```

I have confirmed all my JAR files are in the correct places. I can run the Test.java file just fine on it's own. I have an even larger version of this code and originally assumed it was due to something wrong with the code as a whole, but found it continues even when stripped down to this.

Comment: Figured it out. I had to add all the JAR files to the Run Configurations' classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to add all the JAR files to the Run Configurations classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've added selenium to either your `build.gradle` (`build.gradle.kts`) file or your `pom.xml` as described [in selenium's docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_library/#requirements-by-language).